# como puedo hacer una petición JSON y mostrar los datos en una tableView sin salir de la vista

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

pasa lo siguiente quiero hacer la petición web cuando entre a la vista que seleccione y ver los resultados.

en este momento hago la petición web antes en esta vista:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y cuando abro la siguiente vista
ejemplo restaurante ya aparecen los datos cargados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero lo que yo quiero hacer y he venido intentado, es que al momento de abrir la vista, ejemplo restaurante
me haga la petición y me muestre los datos en la tableView,
pero no me los muestra y es porque no sabe cuantos datos mostrar

intente hacer un refreshControl y un reload a la tableView pero no funciona

algúna idea de que puedo poner?

me gustaría poner una vista que diga cargando y después mostrar la tableView pero no se como poner eso.

Comment: al momento de hacer la petición, no demuestra datos en la tabla, estuve leyendo es porque la petición se hace ne otro hilo y no esta listo para mostrar datos.

Comment: Con la información que das te diría que haces la petición y cuando obtengas la respuesta haces un reload de la tabla con los datos obtenidos. Entiendo que mucho no te sirva este comentario pero podría ser de mucha ayuda si nos muestras el código que has intentado

Answer (score 0):

Segun entendi, la peticion es realizada pero de forma asincrona por lo cual al momento de finalizar no refresca la tabla mostrando los datos como deberia, si es asi entonces la solucion es simple, solo es necesario usar la funcion:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async
{
    //Refrescar la tabla aqui y detener el objeto"cargando"
}
```

Comment: listo así le hice y si pude resolverlo, muchas gracias